# how to display image and file name from sdcard

Tags: android, image-gallery, android-sdcard

I am able to get all images from sdcard,but I want to show file name along with image while listing images from sdcard.Can any one help me to implement this.

Comment: you can use FilenameFilter http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FilenameFilter.html.

Comment: Can you please share the code to get all images from sdCard with us?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will solve it :

```
 File images = Environment.getDataDirectory();   
     File[] imagelist = images.listFiles(new FilenameFilter(){   
     @override  
     public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {   
        return (name.endsWith(".png"))   
     }   
 });
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this answer of SO.[get All image from SD Card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381270/how-to-get-all-image-files-available-in-sdcard-in-android/10381613#10381613). For making work for only .png you need to use below resource array in that answer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string-array name="image">
     <item>png</item>
   </string-array>
</resources>
```